# After adding a row of data to firebase on reload through IOS, data missing

Tags: ios, swift

In IOS, I navigate to a screen and add data via the following code:

```
let dbRow = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("bikes").child(self.userUid).childByAutoId()

dbRow.child("brand").setValue(self.brand.text)
dbRow.child("model").setValue(self.model.text)
dbRow.child("year").setValue(self.year.text)
dbRow.child("serialNo").setValue(self.serialNo.text)
dbRow.child("store").setValue(self.store.text)
dbRow.child("imageURL").setValue(metadata?.downloadURL()!.absoluteString)

self.navigationController!.popViewController(animated: true)
```

after I navigate back and in the `ViewDidLoad` function of the originating screen, I have the following code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("bikes").child(userUid).observe(FIRDataEventType.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

     if snapshot.exists() {
       let bike = Bike()

        bike.bikeKey = snapshot.key
        let bikeDict = snapshot.value as! [String : AnyObject]

        bike.brand = bikeDict["brand"] as! String
        bike.ImageUrl = bikeDict["imageURL"] as! String
        bike.model = bikeDict["model"] as! String
        bike.SerialNo = bikeDict["serialNo"] as! String
        bike.Store = bikeDict["store"] as! String
        bike.year = bikeDict["year"] as! String

        self.bikes.append(bike)
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    //    print(self.bikes.count)
    // method to get current user id  FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
})
```

getting the brand works, but the access to imageURL, returns an error `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION`.  However, on the first time loading the screen all of the rows are returned. Any thoughts?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: At work we have the rule: never unwrap explicitly! 
Better to have missing information than to force a crash. It will save you headaches...

Answer (score 0):

You should reload the data asynchronously. I'm on the phone now and am not sure if this code will work, but you can give it a try:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
```